# Two records being added to table MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

[image: Two records]

I have a form which allows the user add a record to a table but when the Create Operation button is clicked two records are added to the table instead of one. When I add a second the extra record is then changed to the newest record added. This continues to happen and there is always 1 extra record in my table. How would I go about changing this ?

Here is the code I am using to add the record :

```
Private Sub Save_Operation_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


strElement = Me.Element.Value
strOperation = Me.Operation.Value
strProduct = Me.Product_ID.Value
strTime = Me.Time.Value
strQty = Me.Qty.Value




Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Labour", dbOpenTable)

rs.AddNew
rs("Element").Value = strElement
rs("Operation").Value = strOperation
rs("Product_ID").Value = strProduct
rs("Time").Value = strTime
rs("Qty").Value = strQty
rs.Update
```

[image]

Comment: Think to close your recordset and database after query with : `rs.Close` and `db.Close`. Maybe it's not the problem but it's a good practice.

Comment: thanks i will start to do so !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is the use of "addnew" so try this :

```
With rs
   .AddNew
   !Element = strElement
   !Operation = strOperation
   !Product_ID = strProduct
   !Time = strTime
   !Qty = strQty
   .Update
End With
```

Comment: Yes this is the only bit of Code in the form, The first picture in the quesion is the start of a subform of the main form. In the main form the user types the product ID which generates a product record and pass the product_id to the subform thats why its grey out(This is done using embedded macro not vb code). Could my problem be arrising from hear ?

Comment: you could implement in your database a rule with an id of the operation that has to be unique

Comment: Im sorry I dont exactly follow what you say ? still stuck on this problem :(

Comment: I think you should add an id attribute in your table "Labour" and which would be unique to avoid two same lines

Comment: I do have a unique ID its an incremented number that is automaticly set

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem and after a lot of confusion, I figured out the issue for me.  I had set the Control Source on the fields on the form to the table I was adding records to with the button.  I had to remove the Control Source completely, and then the double entries stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer!